# how to push array values in loop using angularjs?

Tags: angularjs

here i am getting all the vales 0 to 4 for every stores but i want 0  for apple 1  for samsung 2  for micromax 3  for nokia and  4 for sony i need to push item values based on the stores so anyone can help how to push value based on the stores in this method i am using ionic frame work collapsible  list, already i attached my code here

```js
angular.module('ionicApp', ['ionic'])

.controller('MyCtrl', function($scope) {
   var stores = ['apple', 'samsung', 'micromax' ,'nokia', 'sony'];
   
  $scope.groups = [];
  for (var i=0; i<stores.length; i++) {
    $scope.groups[i] = {
       name:stores[i],
     
      items: [],
      show: false
    };
     
    for (var j=0; j<5; j++) {
      $scope.groups[i].items.push(j);
    }
  }
  
  /*
   * if given group is the selected group, deselect it
   * else, select the given group
   */
  $scope.toggleGroup = function(group) {
    group.show = !group.show;
  };
  $scope.isGroupShown = function(group) {
    return group.show;
  };
  
});
```

```css
.list .item.item-accordion {
  line-height: 38px;
  padding-top: 0;
  padding-bottom: 0;
  transition: 0.09s all linear;
}
.list .item.item-accordion.ng-hide {
  line-height: 0px;
}
.list .item.item-accordion.ng-hide-add,
.list .item.item-accordion.ng-hide-remove {
  display: block !important;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<html ng-app="ionicApp">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, user-scalable=no">
    <title>Ionic collapsible list</title>
   
    <link href="//code.ionicframework.com/1.0.0-beta.12/css/ionic.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <script src="//code.ionicframework.com/1.0.0-beta.12/js/ionic.bundle.js"></script>
    </script>
  </head>

  <body ng-controller="MyCtrl">
    
    <ion-header-bar class="bar-positive">
      <h1 class="title">Ionic collapsible list</h1>
    </ion-header-bar>

    <ion-content>

      <ion-list>
        <div ng-repeat="group in groups">
          <ion-item class="item-stable"
                    ng-click="toggleGroup(group)"
                    ng-class="{active: isGroupShown(group)}">
              <i class="icon" ng-class="isGroupShown(group) ? 'ion-minus' : 'ion-plus'"></i>
            &nbsp;
            {{group.name}}
          </ion-item>
          <ion-item class="item-accordion"
                    ng-repeat="item in group.items"
                    ng-show="isGroupShown(group)">
            {{item}}
          </ion-item>
        </div>
      </ion-list>

    </ion-content>
      
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: You didn't provide any information about items or its value. So that we can related it from store.

Answer (score 1):

Controller :

```
 angular
  .module('ionicApp', ['ionic'])
  .controller('MyCtrl', function ($scope) {
    var stores = ['apple', 'samsung', 'micromax', 'nokia', 'sony'];

    $scope.groups = [];
    for (var i = 0; i < stores.length; i++) {
      $scope.groups.push({
        name: stores[i],

        items: [],
        show: false
      });

      for (var j = 0; j < 5; j++) {
        $scope.groups[i].items.push(j);
      }
    }

    /*
     * if given group is the selected group, deselect it
     * else, select the given group
     */
    $scope.toggleGroup = function (group) {
      group.show = !group.show;
    };
    $scope.isGroupShown = function (group) {
      return group.show;
    };

  });
```

$scope.groups will result you as below
[image]

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you question correctly, you do not need the second for loop.

In your js file, you have

```
for (var j=0; j<5; j++) {
  $scope.groups[i].items.push(j);
}
```

And I think what you need is just

```
$scope.group[i].items.push(i);
```